# Dynamic string formatting in Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I'm implementing a feature to format a string during text entry using different specifiers e.g:

```
let formatString = "#### #### #### #### ###" // For card number format
```

or

```
let formatString = "##/##" // For expiry month and year (mm/yy)`
```

If the user starts typing card details, e.g
`self.cardNumberTextField = "44624523` this should be formatted to
`4462 4523` using the specified format set. The same also should happen for card expiry dates.

Can anyone help with how to implement this in Swift? Ideally, this formatting should happen as you type in the TextField.

Comment: You should be able to attach a function to an event such as a key up in the textfield. This could modify the content of the textfield to match your format. It might check the format of the content, if it's not correct, then remove all illegal characters before applying your formatting rules.

Comment: Thanks! any sample you could share?

Comment: Glad that makes sense - I don't have Xcode on this machine. This question is still unanswered so others will likely come along in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

play with this in your playground ... try different inputs, less numbers, some characters etc ...

```
let format = "###/# ## XXX ## #### #(#)#"
struct E:ErrorType { var txt = ""}

func formated(str: String, formater: String) throws->String {
    var s = str.characters.generate()
    var res = ""
    let f = formater.characters
    try f.forEach { (c) -> () in
        if c == Character("#") {
            if let q = s.next() {
                if let _ = Int(String(q)) {
                    res.append(q)
                } else {
                    throw E(txt: "input must be a number!!!")
                }
            } else {
                res.append(Character("#"))            }
        } else {
            res.append(c)
        }
    }
    return res
}

do {
    print(try formated("", formater: format))
    print(try formated("1234", formater: format))
    print(try formated("123412345678547", formater: format))
    print(try formated("123a12345678547", formater: format))
} catch let e {
    print((e as? E)?.txt ?? "unknown error")
}

/*
###/# ## XXX ## #### #(#)#
123/4 ## XXX ## #### #(#)#
123/4 12 XXX 34 5678 5(4)7
input must be a number!!!
*/
```